# Communication between two processors (Parallel Programming)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, communication

I want to write a code that:
P0 processor gets an array from keyboard, and sends that array to P1 processor.
P1 processor prints all of the values to screen. For example:

```
[P0]: Enter the size of array: 1
[P0]: Enter the elements of array: 3
[P1]: The array is: 3
[P0]: Enter the size of array: 3
[P0]: Enter the elements of array: 5 7 5
[P1]: The array is: 5 7 5
.
.
.
```

and here is my first work. Too many faults I think. But I'm new. Want to learn how to code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define n 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int my_rank, size_cm;
    int value, i;
    int dizi[n];
    double senddata[n];
    double recvdata[n];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size_cm);

    value=0;

    if(my_rank == 0){
        printf("[%d]: Enter the size of array: ",&my_rank);
        scanf("%d",value);
        printf("[%d]: Enter the elements of array",&my_rank);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            scanf("%d", &dizi[n]);
            senddata[0] = dizi[];
            MPI_Send(senddata, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    if(my_rank == 1){
        MPI_Recv(recvdata, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,    
        printf("[%d]: The array is: %d ",&my_rank, dizi[n]);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you asking for? From what you have posted everything looks like it's working correctly. Please edit your post.

Comment: I have tried to indent correctly your code, a `}` is missing before `if(my_rank == 1)`. And an argument is missing for `MPI_Recv`

Answer (score 0):

To get a minimal example that compile, I added the missing argument to `MPI_Recv()`:

```
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Recv(recvdata, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
```

I also modifed `senddata[0] = dizi[];` to `senddata[0] = dizi[i];`

- As I tried to compile the code you provided, I got a warning :

> format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *

The function `scanf()` needs the pointer to the data to modify it, so `int a;scanf("%d",&a);` is correct. But `printf()` just needs the data since it will not modify it : `int a;printf("%d",a);` is the right way to go.

- If you want the array to be populated, use `scanf("%d", &dizi[i]);`, not `scanf("%d", &dizi[n]);`. `n` is the lenght of array `dizi`. Hence, the index `n` is out of the array, since indexes of arrays start at 0. This could trigger undefined behaviors (strange values, segmentation fault or even a correct result !).
- Since `MPI_Send()` is called in the `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`, process 0 tries to send `n` messages to process 1. But process 1 only receives one. Hence, process 0 will be locked at i=1, waiting for process 1 to receive the second message. This is a deadlock.

I assume you are trying to send an array from process 0 to process 1. The following code based on your should do the trick. The actual length of the array is `n_arr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int my_rank, size_cm;
    int n_arr;
    int i;
    int dizi[n];
    //    double senddata[n];
    //    double recvdata[n];

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size_cm);

    if(my_rank == 0){
        // fflush(stdout); because the standard output is buffered...
        printf("[%d]: Enter the size of array: ",my_rank);fflush(stdout);
        if(scanf("%d",&n_arr)!=1){fprintf(stderr,"input error\n");exit(1);}
        if(n_arr>100){
            fprintf(stderr,"The size of the array is too large\n");exit(1);
        }
        printf("[%d]: Enter the elements of array",my_rank);fflush(stdout);
        for(i=0; i<n_arr; i++){
            if(scanf("%d", &dizi[i])!=1){fprintf(stderr,"input error\n");exit(1);}

        }
        //sending the length of the array
        MPI_Send(&n_arr, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //senfing the array
        MPI_Send(dizi, n_arr, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if(my_rank == 1){
        // receiving the length of the array
        MPI_Recv(&n_arr, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        //receiving the array 
        MPI_Recv(dizi, n_arr, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);    
        printf("[%d]: The array of size %d is: ",my_rank,n_arr);
        for(i=0; i<n_arr; i++){
            printf("%d ",dizi[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

It is compiled by running `mpicc main.c -o main` and ran by `mpirun -np 2 main`

I added some stuff to check if the input is correct (always a good thing) and to handle the case of `n_arr` being larger than n=100. The last one could be avoided by using `malloc()` to allocate memory for the array: this part is left to you !